# Python Pandas Pivot Table group by match_id

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe example:

[image]

match_id, map_type, server and duration_minutes are common variables of a match. In this example we have 5 different matches.

profile_id, country, rating, color, team, civ, won are specific variables for every player that played this specified match.

How can i obtain new dataframe with this structure?
match_id, map_type, server, duration_minutes, profile_id_player1, country_player1, rating_player1, color_player1, team_player1, civ_player1, won_player1, profile_id_player2, country_player2, rating_player2, color_player2, team_player2, civ_player2, won_player2?

Only one row by match_id with all specific variables for every player.

EDIT:This is the result by the solution of @darth baba almost done

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First groupby match_id then aggregate all the other columns to the list and then expand those list to columns, to achieve that try this:

```
df = pd.groupby(['match_id', 'map_type', 'server', 'duration_minutes'])['profile_id', 'country', 'rating', 'color', 'team', 'civ', 'won'].agg(list)

df = pd.concat([df[i].apply(pd.Series).set_index(df.index) for i in df.columns], axis=1).reset_index()

# Rename the columns accordingly
df.columns = [ 'match_id', 'map_type', 'server', 'duration_minutes', 'profile_id_player1', 'country_player1', 'rating_player1', 'color_player1', 'team_player1', 'civ_player1', 'won_player1', 'profile_id_player2', 'country_player2', 'rating_player2', 'color_player2', 'team_player2', 'civ_player2', 'won_player2']
```

Comment: Hi @darth baba, i edited mi question adding new results by your code, is almost done, can you help me? thank you!